# Reverse global and local marks in vi/vim

Tags: vim, vi

How can I reverse the capitalization convention of marks in vi/vim?

Normally a lower-case mark like "a" means it is local to the current file, but upper case marks like "A" are global to the session. Since I normally use only global marks, I want the lower case to be the global marks. In other words I want to reverse the default convention.

Answer (score 4):

The use of uppercase letters as global marks is persistent and, in general, you cannot change this.

But for each letter, you can:

```
nnoremap ma mA
nnoremap `a `A
nnoremap 'a 'A
```